# RecognitionListener callback to onError called multiple times with same error code

Tags: android, speech-recognition

Using `RecognitionListener` interface I'm implementing speech recognition. This interface enabled to implement callback like:

```
public void onError(int error) {

}
```

It works great except one major issue. Callback for onError is called multiple times with same error code. As an example `ERROR_CLIENT` or `ERROR_NO_MATCH`. I see same method is getting callback with same error code at least twice.

What got missed? Or is it a bug in google speech recognition API's?

Comment: please give more details about your code

Comment: I'm using RecognitionListener interface to implement callback on voice recognition. I intend to restart voice recognition in case i receive an error.As an example when google server fails to understand or interpret what i said, it throws error via calling of onError method (it belongs to RecognitionListener interface). When i activate listner using Recognizer object via intent it gives me beep sound and if can speak which google server understand and able to interpret without calling onError. But when i don't speak lister times out and onError method is called multiple times.

Comment: are you sure that you haven't register listener twice ? setRecognitionListener(RecognitionListener listener)

Comment: Yes sir. I rechecked and in-fact rewritten the code to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i have found for this problem is to call `destroy` on SpeechRecognizer. So if you use this remember to instantiate the objects again after you call destroy.

Comment: it's too costly to call destroy entire object and re-construct the object. In my case i have a bind-service which SpeechRecognizer Object. I tried ignoring errors if coming more than once with same error code and after that it works much better.

Comment: So what about calling stopListening on the SpeechRecognizer ? If an error occured such as ERROR_NETWORK the recognizer may continue to listen and pushing the error to your listener over and over again. You could call startListening after a given amount of time or when network service is available again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that you don't create multiple speech recognition objects and setting this interface for all of them?

Comment: Yes sir, i have only one object, this was the first thing i had doubt on when i noticed the behaviour. looks like only solution is for me is to somehow ignore them.